# Rename Variables within lapply fun function

Tags: r, function, variables, rename, lapply

I am not able to get `rename` from `dplyr` to use the a name derived from the input variables when the corrosponding function is called by `lapply`. It always gives only the placeholder `X[[i]]`. Outside `lapply` it works just fine. I don't know what I am missing here. Any suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Working Example:

```
library(dplyr)
fc <- c(1:10)
sc <- c(20:29)
df1 <- cbind.data.frame(fc, sc) #data.frame for function within labbly
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(fc, sc) #data.frame for function without labbly

addfunc <- function(var, df) {
  attach(df)
  dfname = deparse(substitute(df)) #getting df name
  new_var_name = deparse(substitute(var)) #getting var name as string
  new_var_name <- paste(new_var_name, "_new", sep = "") #appending "_new" to var name string
  df <- df %>% mutate(new_var = var + 100) # performing some mutation on var and passing to place holder "new_var"
  df <- df %>% rename(!!new_var_name := new_var) # renaming placeholder "new_var" to "new_var_name"
  assign(dfname, df, envir=globalenv()) # pushing df to global environment
  detach(df)
  }

var <- list(sc, fc) #list with variable from df for lapply

#using function without lapply provides desired result
addfunc(fc, df2)
addfunc(sc, df2)

lapply(var, FUN = addfunc, df=df1) # using function within lapply does not get the new_var_name
```

I tried different kinds of conversion for the input to get its name: `new_var_name = quote(var)`, `new_var_name = as.character(var)`. But no success.

Comment: That's just how `lapply` works. In base R I'd recommend using a `for` loop but there is probably a fancy tidyverse approach. Btw., I'm cringing when looking at your function as it is full of bad practices.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am new to R, so yeah your cringing doesn't surprise me :D. If you have some good practice suggestions to this code, feel free to share.

Comment: Most important: Don't create functions with side effects like assigning into the global environment. Also: Don't use `attach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a better understanding of the fancy tidyverse solutions, I can recommend the [programming with `dplyr` vignette.](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

In the following, I provide two different solutions and have changed the code a bit how I would do it.

- the functions don't have any side effects, they just return the changed data.frame
- `addfunc_1` takes a symbol as input for `var` (i.e. the variable name without quotation marks). In the tidyverse speak, this is a "data-variable in a function argument". Therefore, you need `{{}}` to use the actual value in `dplyr` functions.
- `addfunc_2` takes a string as input for `var` (i.e. the variable name with quotation marks). In the tidyverse speak, this is a "env-variable that is a character vector". Therefore, you need to use `.data` to index by name the respective column in `dplyr` functions.
- if you just use `lapply` with `list(sc, fc)` without first initialising the variables (I changed how to create the data.frame and therefore haven't), it gives an error because it doesn't find these variables. You can use `rlang::sym` to circumvent this problem.
- note that if you first initialise `sc` and `fc` as you did in your example, `lapply` doesn't give an error, but it uses the data stored in these variables and passes it to the `addfunc` function, leading to unwanted behaviour

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  fc = 1:10,
  sc = 20:29
)

# use symbols for var
addfunc_1 <- function(var, df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate("{{var}}_new" := {{var}} + 100)
}

# use strings for var
addfunc_2 <- function(var, df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate("{var}_new" := .data[[var]] + 100)
}

lapply(list(rlang::sym("sc"), rlang::sym("fc")), addfunc_1, df1)
#> [[1]]
#>    fc sc sc_new
#> 1   1 20    120
#> 2   2 21    121
#> 3   3 22    122
#> 4   4 23    123
#> 5   5 24    124
#> 6   6 25    125
#> 7   7 26    126
#> 8   8 27    127
#> 9   9 28    128
#> 10 10 29    129
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    fc sc fc_new
#> 1   1 20    101
#> 2   2 21    102
#> 3   3 22    103
#> 4   4 23    104
#> 5   5 24    105
#> 6   6 25    106
#> 7   7 26    107
#> 8   8 27    108
#> 9   9 28    109
#> 10 10 29    110

lapply(list("sc", "fc"), addfunc_2, df1)
#> [[1]]
#>    fc sc sc_new
#> 1   1 20    120
#> 2   2 21    121
#> 3   3 22    122
#> 4   4 23    123
#> 5   5 24    124
#> 6   6 25    125
#> 7   7 26    126
#> 8   8 27    127
#> 9   9 28    128
#> 10 10 29    129
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    fc sc fc_new
#> 1   1 20    101
#> 2   2 21    102
#> 3   3 22    103
#> 4   4 23    104
#> 5   5 24    105
#> 6   6 25    106
#> 7   7 26    107
#> 8   8 27    108
#> 9   9 28    109
#> 10 10 29    110
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Edit

For your usecase, it's probably the easiest to just use `across` with `mutate` as you can directly there specify how the new columns should be generated:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(fc, sc), ~.x + 100, .names = "{.col}_new"))
```

Comment: Phenomenal! Thank you so much for this solution and explenation! Gave me a clear understanding :)

Comment: Two quick follow up questions: 1) What exactly do you mean with "initialize the variables first" (bullet 4), 'attach'? 2) Is it possible to get a "growing" data.frame where `sc_new` and `fc_new` appear in the same data.frame behind `fc` and `sc`? And one last thing, when I just use `list(sc, fc)` in the `addfunc_1` (and not `list(rlang::sym("sc"), rlang::sym("fc"))`) I just get `<int>_new`. Maybe I have not understood something correctly.

Comment: With initialise first, I mean `fc <- c(1:10); sc <- c(20:29)` instead of directly using `df1 <- data.frame(fc = 1:10, sc = 20:29)`. this means that in your environment there are now the integer vectors `fc` and `sc`. This also explains why you just get `<int>_new`, because the dplyr functions then use the content of the symbols as passed by `lapply` to derive the name instead of using an unevaluated symbol as represented by `rlang::sym`

Comment: Dear starja, thanks to your pointers I now have fully understood what is going on with `dplyr` and found a (the?) cheat sheet (https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/data-transformation.pdf) :D. I googled my hands bloody for so many problems that are all so very easily solved with this. I don't know why it was so hard to find. Maybe because it is conceived too fancy for many in the r community. Anyways, I just wanted to thank you again, you helped out a nooby a lot! Blessings.